# Create Custom Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a Custom Sequence which should create sequence for below ranges
`XV00AA-XV99ZZ` and many other ranges

Example:

```
XV00AA, XV01AA, XV02AA, ......XV99AA
```

The first 2 characters remain the same (example - XV series); the last 2 characters remain the same (example - AA series); but the middle 2 characters should increment from 0 to 99. (Example `XV01AA, XV02AA, XV03AA` and so on)

Once it reaches 99 (i.e. `XV99AA`) then it should repeat for AB series
So output should be

```
XV00AB, XV01AB, XV02AB, .....XV99AB
```

And then

```
XV00AC,XV01AC,XV02AC....XV99AC
```

So sample final output:

```
XV00AA
XV01AA
XV02AA
....
XV99AA
XV00AB
XV01AB
XV02AB
....
XV99AB
XV00AC
XV01AC
XV02AC
...
XV99AC
XV00AD
XV01AD
XV02AD
...
XV99AD
```

and so on. Is there any easy way to create these series? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please share with us what research have you already done on this issue.

Comment: If `XV` part is truly constant then such a sequence can only provide you with 100 * 26^2 = 67600 unique values. Create a permanent table with all possible values and (re)use them from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
DECLARE @how_many_do_you_want INT = 67599;  -- 67599 is where it runs out of legit values.

WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),
    cte_Tally (n) AS (
        SELECT TOP (@how_many_do_you_want)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
            cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b
        )
SELECT 
    rn = t.n,
    CONCAT('XV', cn.char_num, a.alpha_1, a.alpha_2)
FROM
    cte_Tally t
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (t.n % 100) ) m (mod_100)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (((t.n - m.mod_100) / 100) % 26 + 1) ) g1 (group_1)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (t.n / 2600 + 1) ) g2 (group_2)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (RIGHT(CONCAT('0', m.mod_100), 2)) ) cn (char_num)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CHAR(g1.group_1 + 64), CHAR(g2.group_2 + 64)) ) a (alpha_1, alpha_2);
```

Comment: The requested prefix is `'XV'`, not `'VX'`.

Comment: @HABO - Thank you. Good catch. It's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses a CTE to generate a table of numbers from 0 to 67,599. The values are then split apart: modulus (`%`) provides the value for the digits and integer division (`/`) provides the value for the letters. A little fiddling for formatting and conversion and Bob's your uncle.

```
with Numbers as (
  select 0 as N
  union all
  select N + 1
    from Numbers
    where N < 67599 )
  select N, N % 100 as DigitsValue, N / 100 as LettersValue,
    Right( '0' + Cast( N % 100 as VarChar(2) ), 2 ) as LeftPaddedDigits,
    Char( ASCII( 'A' ) + ( N / 100 ) % 26 ) as LeastSignificantLetter,
    Char( ASCII( 'A' ) + ( N / 100 ) / 26 ) as MostSignificantLetter
    from Numbers
  option ( MaxRecursion 0 )
```

Putting the complete string together with "XV" as a prefix is left to the reader.